# Penalizing documents in facet results based on their content

Tags: search, elasticsearch, faceted-search, facet

If we have the following documents in elasticsearch:

```
[
    {'name': 'John', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:01:00'},
    {'name': 'John', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:02:00'},
    {'name': 'John', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:03:00'},
    {'name': 'John', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:04:00'},
    {'name': 'Harry', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:05:00'},
    {'name': 'Fred', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:06:00'},
    {'name': 'Fred', 'time': '2013-01-01 12:07:00'}
]
```

And we facet over the 'name' field, we'll get something like this:

```
 "facets": {
   "count_per_name": {
      "_type": "terms",
      "missing": 0,
      "total": 7,
      "other": 0,
      "terms": [
         {
            "term": "John",
            "count": 4
         },
         {
            "term": "Fred",
            "count": 2
         },
         {
            "term": "Harry",
            "count": 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My question is this: is it possible to perform a faceting query in elasticsearch whereby those documents with the `name` "John" count as "half" documents? This would lead to John's count falling from 4 to 2, but Fred's and Harry's remaining the same:

```
 "facets": {
   "count_per_name": {
      "_type": "terms",
      "missing": 0,
      "total": 5,
      "other": 0,
      "terms": [
         {
            "term": "John",
            "count": 2
         },
         {
            "term": "Fred",
            "count": 2
         },
         {
            "term": "Harry",
            "count": 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could play with http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-stats-facet.html

and specify value_script, where return 0.5 for John and 1 for other guys, and operate with SUM facet result. Though this approach is performance affected